# Encoding 16 variables into one

Tags: encoding

I have 16 variables (each variable can take value between 1 and 56) how can I encode the value of these 16 variables into one variable ? For example {1,15,22,32,21,2,3,5,6,4,5,6,7,8,8,2} needs to be encoded and output can be something to decode the exact value of each variable

Comment: It looks like you already provided one possible encoding: Encode them in the string `"{1,15,22,32,21,2,3,5,6,4,5,6,7,8,8,2}"`.

Comment: Actually, I need to send them on wire (websocket packet) and need to compress the size.

Comment: You need to explain what your requirements are. Otherwise every time somebody proposes an answer, you'll say "No, I can't use that because ..."

Comment: Why not sending 16 bytes? one per value (your "variable"). Not the most efficient, but good enough. Else you can see that 56 values can be stored in 6 bits, so just prepare a series of 6 bits, and convert numerically. Or ... you have so many choices, and your question it too generic.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to actual development actually. Will use series of 6 bits. THanks